# How to inject service from external file using AngularJS and RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, requirejs

I'm injecting controller from external file and I want to do the same thing for the service from external file. It should be registered in factory statement.

Injecting of the controller working

*controllers*

```
'use strict';

define(['angular', 'services'], function (angular) {
    return angular.module('vcApp.controllers', ['vcApp.services'])
        .controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', '$injector','AuthService', function($scope, $injector, AuthService) {
            require(['auth/authCtrl'], function(authCtrl) {
                $injector.invoke(authCtrl, this, {'$scope': $scope, 'AuthService':AuthService});
            });
        }]);
});
```

*authCtrl*

```
define([], function() {
    return ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http', 'AuthService', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $http, authService) {

        $scope.signIn = function() {
        ...
        }

        $scope.$apply();
    }];
});
```

And now I want to inject service

*services*

```
'use strict';

define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    angular.module('vcApp.services', [])
    .factory('AuthService', ['$http', '$injector', function($http, $injector) {
        require(['auth/authService'], function(authService) {
            $injector.invoke(authService, this, {'$http': $http});
        });
    }]);
});
```

*authService*

```
define([], function() {
    return ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            login: login
        };

        function login(username, password) {
            var request = $http(...);
            return(request);
        }
    }]
});
```

When authController calls `authService.login(...)`, it throws error `Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'AuthService' must return a value from $get factory method.`.

This code was inspired by [angular-requirejs-seed](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed) project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says, Angular's `factory()` is expected to return the service object. You may have luck with something like:

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    angular.module('vcApp.services', [])
    .factory('AuthService', ['$http', '$injector', function($http, $injector) {
        var stub = {};
        require(['auth/authService'], function(authService) {
            angular.extend(stub, $injector.invoke(authService, this, {'$http': $http}));
        });
        return stub;
    }]);
});
```

Here you define a stub for the service and extend it, when the service is actually lazy-loaded.

(By the way I think the last 2 arguments of `$injector.invoke()` are redundant in this case.)

If you want another idea about mixing RequireJS and Angular, that plays well with lazy loading and the r.js optimizer, you may take a look at [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy).